# how to change teaser display output via views

Tags: views

I have a view that is displaying teasers of a content type. I would like to change order of one of the fields to come AFTER node links, any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you go to admin/structure/types/manage/name_content_type/display/teaser.  You can change the order that fields display in your teaser and this will change also how it looks in your view.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have thought of that but that wouldn't change order of where to display node links. they're not a field that can be repositioned graphically.

Comment: if you want to control even more the way you node display fields..take a look of the module display suite, there are good videos of the module. But in views you can also choose instead of displaying the teasers, use your view to display  fields instead.

Answer (score 2):

Download and enable [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

Then go to /admin/structure/types/manage/{content-type}/display/teaser and select layout of your choice.

[image]

Then add the links feature to the region of your choice

[image]

Comment: I simply had to change views output to fields!